# Limpiar formulario despues de enviar correo

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buen día,
Estoy armando una pagina institucional y tengo un formulario de contacto simple que manda un mail al clickear el botón **"enviar"**, el form va a una pagina php aparte para armar el modelo y enviarlo.
Si no hubo ningún problema el mensaje se envía y genero un alert para avisar que se mando el mensaje, sino es así sale un alert con el error.
 
Mi problema esta en que al enviar el formulario y regresar a la pagina principal no me limpia el formulario.
Probé de todo, no uso Ajax; nose si debería usarlo? soy todavía inexperto en programación web
Gracias
Esto seria la parte del formulario:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" class="formulario" id="form-comun">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <span>
                                Seleccione una Opcion:
                            </span>
                            <select name="seleccion" id="seleccion" class="custom-select mb-3" onchange="controlTipo()">
                                <option value="1">Consultas</option>
                                <option value="2">Sugerencias/Reclamos</option>
                                <option value="3">Enviar Curriculum Vitae</option>
                            </select>                                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" value="" required>                     
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" name="correo" id="mail" placeholder="Email" value="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea name="comentario" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" value=""></textarea>
                    <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="boton" value="Enviar" id="enviar">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="limpiar">                        
            </form>
```

En el php lo unico que hago es obtener los datos por POST y crear un mail con phpmailer. Las ultimas lineas donde controlo si funciona es:

```
$mail->send();

        echo "<script>alert('Mensaje enviado correctamente');</script>";
        echo "<script>location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
            echo "<script>alert('Su formulario no pudo ser enviado exitosamente, Verifique el error');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
            }
```

Comment: Te recuerdo que para que te podamos apoyar, debes incluir el código que llevas. Ahora, deberías usar AJAX, Enviar información por el método tradicional de `form` quedó en el pasado. Esto debido a que la respuesta de PHP debe hacer un render de una página nueva (Puede ser redirección nuevamente al formulario) y trabajar los mensajes que se retornan por la URL, ya es la vieja usanza.

Comment: Buen día @Diego Leguizamon considera darte un paseo por el [tour] y de paso leer [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

crea un botón oculto dentro del formularo que sea `type="reset"`

y has un script que al cargar la página le de click al botón.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mail.php" method="post" class="formulario" id="form-comun">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
            <span>Seleccione una Opcion:</span>
            <select name="seleccion" id="seleccion" class="custom-select mb-3" onchange="controlTipo()">
                <option value="1">Consultas</option>
                <option value="2">Sugerencias/Reclamos</option>
                <option value="3">Enviar Curriculum Vitae</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" value="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <input type="email" name="correo" id="mail" placeholder="Email" value="" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="comentario" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" value="">Debería borrarse este texto</textarea>
    <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="boton" value="Enviar" id="enviar">
    </div>
    <button type="reset" id="limpiar" hidden=""></button>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#limpiar").click();
        $("#form-comun > textarea").html("");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Esta es la mejor opción Diego Leguizamon, te recomiendo usar esta, justamente iba a responder lo mismo.

Comment: Buenas tardes, Ok lo voy a intentar así.
Gracias

Comment: @Kevin Delva me das una mano con el script, estoy medio perdido.
Gracias

Comment: @DiegoLeguizamon edita la publicación y agrega lo que tienes y te ayudaré en esta misma respuesta

Comment: Ahi lo cargue @Kevin Delva

Comment: actualizado @DiegoLeguizamon

Comment: @KevinDelva cargue tal cual pero me da un error el navegador **TypeError: "#limpiar".click is not a function**
Igual en esta linea **$("form textarea").html("");** no deberia ir el ID del form?
Gracias nuevamente

Comment: @DiegoLeguizamon puede ser, he actualizado el código

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS @KevinDelva Funciono Perfecto, igual tratare de cambiar a Ajax como me dijeron en el primer comentario. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puede funcionar que en tu segundo archivo donde tienes toda la instrucción a tu base de datos, al final coloques:

```
header('Location: tupagina.php');
```

de esta manera refrescas dicha página y tu formulario queda limpio nuevamente